# Prolog: Replace fact using fact

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I am trying to implement a predicate `replace(+OldFact,+NewFact)`
which succeed only if the OldFact existed. If this succeeds then the
NewFact must be added to the set of clauses and the OldFact must be
deleted.

How do I do this?
I am not able to figure out clearly that how to achieve this
replacement using facts as well as how to use those assert and retract
database manipulation commands.

Thanks.

Comment: You can just call `OldFact` to determine if it is in the database. `call(OldFact)` will succeed if it is. Then you can use `retract/1` and `assertz/1` to do what you wish. The list example code you are showing isn't relevant unless what you want to do is have a list of terms for replacement rather than asserted facts.

Comment: Are you really sure you want to modify Prolog predicates? Your definition does not look like it

Comment: @lurker. Thanks. Actually yes, I wanted to replace old fact for a new fact. And if the old fact is found in the database, then it is deleted and a new fact is inserted in the database. The predicate implementation is something like : replace(Oldfact, NewFact).

Comment: @false. I modified my question  little. Actually the code example I gave was not so much relevant to my question.

Comment: I made suggestions in my first comment on things to look at which would be the basis of your approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I take the request at face value, you only need to use the predicates I mentioned in my comment. Your predicate would look something like this:

```
replace_existing_fact(OldFact, NewFact) :-
    (   call(OldFact)
    ->  retract(OldFact),
        assertz(NewFact)
    ;   true
    ).
```

I'm assuming that if the `OldFact` is not found, then you want the predicate simply to succeed. If failure of the predicate is acceptable if the old fact doesn't exist, this would be written simply:

```
replace_existing_fact(OldFact, NewFact) :-
    call(OldFact),
    retract(OldFact),
    assertz(NewFact).
```

---

Note that if you have more than one same `OldFact` in the database, this predicate will backtrack for each one, replacing one occurrence on each backtrack. If you only want to replace one of them, you could use a cut:

```
replace_existing_fact(OldFact, NewFact) :-
    call(OldFact), !,   % Don't backtrack to find multiple instances of old fact
    retract(OldFact),
    assertz(NewFact).
```

Alternatively, if you want to replace each one without being prompted for backtracking:

```
replace_each_existing_fact(OldFact, NewFact) :-
    forall(replace_existing_fact(OldFact, NewFact), true).
```

Comment: What if there are multiple facts, say `f(1). f(1).`?

Comment: @lurker. Thank you so much. Now I understand the implementation of these retract and assert commands. It will help me a lot further to solve more questions.